# In Android, media player not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The media player is not working when I try the following:

```
             player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mh);
             player.start();
```

I receive this error:

> The method create(Context, int) in the
>   type MediaPlayer is not applicable for
>   the arguments (new
>   View.OnClickListener(){}, int)

Answer (score 6):

It is probably because this code is located inside of another class / anonymous class. You should not use `this`, but `MyActivityClassName.this` whatever your activity name is.

Answer (score -1):

u can try this

```
MediaPlayerInstance.play(this, R.raw.mh);
```